# How can select a item from listbox binding Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

I can't get a text from listbox with SELECTEDITEM event but it doesn't and only return a string like "Li.Medicamento".

My code xaml:

`<ListBox x:Name="list_enfer" Margin="38,210,40,65" Visibility="Collapsed">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding enfermedadasoc}"></TextBlock>
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>`

My code in C# is the next:

`private void visualizar_est_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(list_enfer.SelectedItem.ToString()); 
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void visualizar_est_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
             var mySelectedItem = list_enfer.SelectedItem as yourObject;
             //Then you can access the property inside yourObject
             MessageBox.Show(yourObject.enfermedadasoc.ToString()); 
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you mention yourObject?

Comment: @user3621634 The class name you are binding in your code to the listbox. post the part where you set the ItemsSource